# Not matching answer choices -- Finding the number of strings of a certain quality from a set

Tags: probability

I'm correcting an old exam and there are several questions like this, all of which I got wrong and cannot figure out why even when I near brute force it. The question is:

How many strings of length 4 from set {0,1,2,3,4} begin and end in an even number?

I tried 2 * 5 * 5 * 2 and got 100.

The answer choices are:
a. 225
b. 369
c. 500
d. 781

What's going on here? What am I missing?

Comment: Did you perhaps not notice that $0$ is even?

Comment: 0 is not considered even here, the teacher said so while the exam was in progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that an even number is a number with the property $n = 2k$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$. For $k=0$ we see that $0 = 2\cdot 0$ is even as well, so $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ contains three (3) even numbers. Thus
$$N = 3\cdot5\cdot5\cdot3=15^2 = 225$$
Wich means (a) is correct. Your teacher seems not to have noticed that the only valid answer correctly considers $0$ as even.

Fun facts:

- $781$ is impossible because $5^4 = 625 < 781$
- $369$ is impossible if the middle numbers are arbitrary because $25\not|\ \ 369$
- $500$ is obtained by "The number of four-digit numbers with only digits between $0$ and $4$".